# Updating a comma delimited string list in c#

Tags: c#

I have a comma delimited string list that looks something like this:

```
Cat, Animal, 2
Dog, Animal, 3
Luke, Human, 1
Owl, Animal, 0
```

Now i want to search the list, Find all string elements with animal in them and add one to their number. So in the end of my query the list would look like:

```
Cat, Animal, 3
Dog, Animal, 4
Luke, Human, 1
Owl, Animal, 1
```

How can i achieve this functionality? I was thinking of using a LINQ query to get all the entries that contain animal and then getting the index of each element in the list, getting all the tokens in each element by using a comma split, parsing the third token into an integer, incrementing by one and rewriting the element at the previously saved index to update the count. This is probably the least efficient method so can anyone suggest a fast, short and sweet solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: How is the original list stored? Is it in one large string object, an array of strings, a file on disk, etc.? From the description I assume it's a `List<string>` with each item being one line of your example data, but I want to be sure before considering approaches.

Comment: I don't suppose this is in a database table somewhere?

Comment: Brief comment: what you have there is an anti-pattern known as “stringly-typed data”. You should strive to replace the strings by a “real” data type, namely a tuple of two strings (the animal, the category) and an integer (the counter). Then your problem becomes vastly simpler.

Comment: You are correct, each line above is an element of a List<string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first create a class to hold each item in the list.

```
public class Creature
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Species { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public Creature(string name, string species, int count)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Species = species;
        this.Count = count;
    }

    public void Add(int numToAdd)
    {
        this.Count += numToAdd;
    }
    }

public static class CreatureStorage
{
    private static bool isInitialized = false;

    private static List<Creature> creatureList = new List<Creature>();

    public static List<Creature> CreatureList
    {
        get {
                if (isInitialized == false)
                {
                    Initialize();
                }

                return creatureList; 
            }
        set { creatureList = value; }
    }

    public static void Add(string species, int numToAdd)
    {
        foreach (Creature creature in creatureList)
        {
            if (creature.Species.Equals(species))
            {
                creature.Add(numToAdd);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        // Add code to parse through your initial list whether it's a txt file or just a string in the application

        isInitialized = true;
    }
```

Example usage.

```
   public partial class ProcessAnimals : Form
    {
        public ProcessAnimals()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void processAnimals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreatureStorage.Add("Animal", 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: An off topic sort of question: Why exactly is the creature storage class static? ive never really understood the meaning behind a static class and what it means?

Comment: @Holly:
Static classes can't be instantiated or destroyed. They exist for the lifetime of the application (as long as the program is running). 

In this case it's used for an "in memory cache" which is only created once (when the program starts) versus "CreatureStorage storage = new CreatureStorage();" every time you want access to the CreatureStorage.Add feature (inefficient especially if you're pulling data out of a database every time the object is created).

Comment: Why would you need CreatureStorage storage = new CreatureStorage(); declared everytime you need a method in that class? Wouldnt you only instantiate that class once and, as long as you are calling Add from the same method as your instantiation of the class, it will keep working?

Comment: If you are only going to call that class once then you probably don't need the class to be static. However, if you end up needing access to that class in lots of places in your application it would be more efficient to have it as a static class and not have to create a new instance every time. It doesn't have to be a static class it's up to you as the developer to make that decision.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to create a class that represents a row of your list, instead of splitting and searching the strings which is quite inefficient especially if you process the list multiple times, e.g.

```
public class Creature
{
  public string Name { get; set; };
  public string Species  { get; set; };
  public int Count { get; set; };
}
```

These stored in a list can be accessed more easily. The contents of your strings have to be converted twice: 1st at the start of your program if you read them from a file, and 2nd at the end if you want to store them again.

You can get the results you search for with LINQ like this then:

```
listOfCreatures.Where(creature => creature.Species == "Animal").ToList();
```

Comment: Its a little late to create a class and store the contents in a list that way

Comment: Why is it to late? You can parse your strings anytime you like (make sure its only done once), and maybe you can even improve code readability like that :)

Comment: This (or a variant thereof) is the proper way. Using anything else is the way to slavery.

Comment: Hmm, can you explain a little more as to what you do with the class? like if i want to access an element of the list, how does the class work? When building the list for ex, do i just list.Add(Name,Species,Count)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that demostrates what you are describing:

```
    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var content = new string[] { "Cat, Animal, 2", "Dog, Animal, 3", "Luke, Human, 1", "Owl, Animal, 0" };
            foreach (var item in content)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(IncrementIfKeywordFound(item, "Animal"));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string IncrementIfKeywordFound(string data, string keyword)
        {
            var parts = data.Split(new [] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (parts[1] == keyword) parts[2] = (Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) + 1).ToString();
            return string.Join(", ", parts);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a List or anything that can be converted to such

```
for(i = 0;i < yourList.Count; i++)
{
   String str = yourList[i];
   if(str.Contains("Animal")
   {
       var parts = string.Split(@',');
       parts[2] = Integer.Parse(parts[2]) + 1;
       str = String.Join(parts, ",");
   }
}
```

Read once, write only if changes needed.

Comment: Yea thats more or less what i was thinking of. Hmm this seems to be the only way so far... even though it is still inefficient

Comment: @Holly string manipulation really isn't efficient. You can't use a foreach since you can't modify a collection while using the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions. Just for kicks, don't do it this way, it's not very flexible nor maintainable.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string source = @"Cat, Animal, 2
Dog, Animal, 3
Luke, Human, 1
Owl, Animal, 0";

            System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@", Animal, (\d+)");
            foreach (string line in source.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {

                System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection collection = r.Matches(line);
                if (collection.Count == 1)
                {
                    int val = -1;
                    int.TryParse(collection[0].Groups[1].Value, out val);
                    Console.WriteLine(line.Replace(val.ToString(), (val + 1).ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer as a single Linq expression:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>();
source.Add("Cat, Animal, 2");
source.Add("Dog, Animal, 3");
source.Add("Luke, Human, 1");
source.Add("Owl, Animal, 0");

List<string> dest = new List<string>(
    source
        .Select(s => s.Split(new []{',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .Select(s => { if(s[1] == "Animal") s[2] = (Convert.ToInt32(s[2]) + 1).ToString(); return s; })
        .Select(s => String.Join(", ", s))
    );
```

Comment: Though this directly answers the question posed, I do believe that the answer given by Vash of creating a class and strongly representing the data is the "correct" solution to this problem (if feasable, which it might not be).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would your method be more efficient than msarchet? They both seem to run through the list multiple times...

Comment: @Holly - it's probably not much more efficient. Both answers follow the same logic and would therefore have very similar performance characteristics. In fact, the other approach may be slightly more efficient on long lists because it only iterates once. This approach iterates over the list three times (or rather iterates over the original list once and then a temporary in-memory list twice). On the other hand, I personally find terse Linq and extension methods statements easier to read and maintain, but YMMV (it took me a while to be comfortable with the syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Here would be one sketchy example. Load the CSV into a "table" and just modify it and write back to file.

```
public static List<string[]> LoadCSV() {
    List<string[]> table = new List<string[]>();

    // Replace the below with something like File.ReadAllLines(...);
    string[] lines = "Cat, Animal, 3\r\nDog, Animal, 4\r\nLuke, Human, 1\r\nOwl, Animal, 1"
        .Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    foreach (string line in lines) {
        table.Add(line.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None));
    }

    return table;
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    List<string[]> items = LoadCSV();

    foreach (string[] item in items) {
        if (item[2] == "Animal") {
            item[2] = (int.Parse(item[1]) + 1).ToString();
        }
    }

    // Write back to file
}
```

Rather though, you could create a AnimalList class to store a collection of type class 'Animal' that would define properties Animal/Type/Value (or what you wish to call them), and write your own Add/Remove/Save/Load methods.